# Tkinter - canvas side by side issue

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm having an issue to put canvas side by side on my script.
I want to create 5 boxes which each one will be fulfilled by user the quantity of cars sold, in order to save space on my layout, I want to put these 5 boxes in the same line (side by side)

So far, i got the following situation using the script below (boxes under each other)

[image]

```
    Label(self.canvas, text='North', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
    self.nom4=Entry(self.canvas,width=10,bg="white",\
                   fg="blue")
    self.nom4.pack()

    Label(self.canvas, text='Northeast', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
    self.nom5=Entry(self.canvas,width=10,bg="white",\
                   fg="blue")
    self.nom5.pack()

    Label(self.canvas, text='Midwest', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
    self.nom6=Entry(self.canvas,width=10,bg="white",\
                   fg="blue")
    self.nom6.pack()

    Label(self.canvas, text='Southeast', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
    self.nom7=Entry(self.canvas,width=10,bg="white",\
                   fg="blue")
    self.nom7.pack()

    Label(self.canvas, text='South', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
    self.nom8=Entry(self.canvas,width=10,bg="white",\
                   fg="blue")
    self.nom8.pack()
```

How do i put these boxes side by side?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to put the 'boxes' in `Frame`s and display them using [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) with `side` option is set as `'left'`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)


frame4 = Frame(canvas)
Label(frame4, text='North', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
nom4=Entry(frame4,width=10,bg="white", fg="blue")
nom4.pack()
frame4.pack(side='left')

frame5 = Frame(canvas)
Label(frame5, text='Northeast', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
nom5=Entry(frame5,width=10,bg="white", fg="blue")
nom5.pack()
frame5.pack(side='left')

frame6 = Frame(canvas)
Label(frame6, text='Midwest', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
nom6=Entry(frame6,width=10,bg="white", fg="blue")
nom6.pack()
frame6.pack(side='left')

frame7 = Frame(canvas)
Label(frame7, text='Southeast', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
nom7=Entry(frame7,width=10,bg="white", fg="blue")
nom7.pack()
frame7.pack(side='left')

frame8 = Frame(canvas)
Label(frame8, text='South', bg="gray", fg="black").pack() 
nom8=Entry(frame8,width=10,bg="white", fg="blue")
nom8.pack()
frame8.pack(side='left')


canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note: This begs for a box class.

---

Example with `Box` class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Box(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, cardinal_direction):
        super().__init__(master)

        tk.Label(self, text=cardinal_direction, bg="gray", fg="black").pack()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=10,bg="white", fg="blue")
        self.entry.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root)

    boxes = dict()

    for card_dir in ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']:
        boxes[card_dir] = Box(canvas, card_dir)
        boxes[card_dir].pack(side='left')

    canvas.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @RafaelRodriguesSantos No problem. Always happy to be able to solve a well asked question.